# Ошибка синтаксиса в команде copy con (cmd)

Tags: cmd

Здравствуйте. Сегодня столкнулся с очень страннім вопросом.
Создал каталог **Network** (в **Documents and Settings** используя md). Перешел в него используя cd. После этого уже в **Network** через вышеупомянутый md cоздал в нем подкаталог **New**. И тут началось самое интересное: надо в каталоге **New** создать файл с расширением *.doc. Пишу **copy con C:\Documents and Settings\Network\New\1.doc** ошибка в синтаксисе. Если написать copy con **C:\1.doc** - создает.
Обошел проблему, перейдя через **cd** в сам каталог **New**, а в нем **copy con 1.doc**. 
Дело в текущем каталоге? Если да то почему находясь в **Network** можно создать файл в **C:**, но не можна в **C:\Documents and Settings\Network\New**? Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Попробуйте путь к C:\Documents and Settings\Network\New\1.doc взять в кавычки...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, спасибо помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> copy con C:\Documents and Settings\Network\New\1.doc
> ```

```
copy con "C:\Documents and Settings\Network\New\1.doc"
```

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ

Answer (score 0):

Вобщем я сделал все иначе чем в первый раз. Во первых, я не бегал по каталогам используя cd, а создавал подкаталоги прописывая абсолютные пути. Во вторых, взял пути в кавычки, как мне и посоветовали.